# Diferença em meses de data em postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Preciso pegar a diferença de duas datas meses, por exemplo 16/03/2013 até a data 16/07/2014. Se eu fizer

```
select extract('Month' from age(data1, data2))
```

O que irá retornar é um resultado `4`, pois ele informa que a diferença entra a data é de 1 ano de 4 meses.

Porém o que preciso é total em meses ou seja, `15` meses de diferença. Existe alguma forma?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existe no PostgreSQL a *function* `Age` que ao meu ver retrata bem a diferença entre as datas. A SQL abaixo demonstra também o resultado de diferença de meses entre duas datas:

```
SELECT ((ANOS * 12) + MESES) AS MESES
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    CAST(TO_CHAR(AGE(data2, data1),'YY') AS INTEGER) AS ANOS,
    CAST(TO_CHAR(AGE(data2, data1),'MM') AS INTEGER) AS MESES, 
    CAST(TO_CHAR(AGE(data2, data1),'DD') AS INTEGER) AS DIAS
  FROM tabela
) AS tabela
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/cd3a5/1)

Comment: Só queria entender o voto negativo, tinha +1 e foi retirado por qual motivo?

Answer (score 7):

Você pode conseguir o valor em meses extraindo as partes manualmente e fazendo as operações matemáticas envolvidas. Infelizmente o PostgreSQL não possui uma função `DATEDIFF` para simplificar esses cálculos:

```
  SELECT (DATE_PART('year', data2) - DATE_PART('year', data1)) * 12 
         + (DATE_PART('month', data2) - DATE_PART('month', data1));
```

**Fontes:**

- [PostgreSQL - DATEDIFF - Datetime Difference in Seconds, Days, Months, Weeks etc - SQLines](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff)
- [PostgreSQL Wiki - Working with Dates and Times in PostgreSQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_PostgreSQL)

Comment: Na verdade tive um problema com a data, o mês se eu tiver utilizando data do ano passado da negativo. Por exemplo, `(DATE_PART('month', now()) - DATE_PART('month', '12/12/2013':timestamp))`.

Comment: Que é o resultado esperado ão é mesmo? `12/2013` para `08/2014`. Primeira conta `= 1 ano = 12 meses`. Segunda conta: agosto até dezembro `= 8 - 12 = -4 meses`. de `12/2013` até `08/2014` = `12 - 4` = `8 meses`.

Comment: Enfim, se você quiser sempre valores absolutos você pode usar a função [`abs(x)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-math.html) ou garantir que a maior data seja sempre usada como `data2` no seu `select`. Caso contrário você terá sim casos como `12/2013 - 08/2014` cujo resultado retornará, corretamente, `-8` meses.

Answer (score 2):

Se é necessário somente o numero inteiro de meses:

```
select
    (
        select count(*) - 1
        from generate_series(date1, date2, '1 month')
    ) as meses
from (values
    ('2013-03-16'::date, '2014-07-16'::date)
) g (date1, date2)
;
 meses 
-------
    16
```

Answer (score -2):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:
(extract('Year' from AGE('2023-02-28', '2002-01-31'))*12) + extract('Month' from AGE('2023-02-28', '2002-01-31'))

A função AGE(datafinal, datainicial) retorna a diferença em anos, mês e dias.

O primeiro EXTRACT pega a diferença em anos e multiplica por 12 para sabermos quantos meses.
extract('Year' from AGE('2023-02-28', '2002-01-31'))*12

O segundo extract pega os meses retornados.
extract('Month' from AGE('2023-02-28', '2002-01-31')

Faz-se a soma dos valores e no fim temos a quantidade em meses.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).